# jquery how to insert html construct without the close tag

Tags: jquery

I am try to inset html construct without the close tag, cant get the soln.. can any one help?

HTML:

```
<button>Insert span element after each p element</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
```

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("<span>").insertAfter("p");
  });
});
</script>
```

In run time if we debug i am getting html like below:

```
<button>Insert span element after each p element</button>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<span></span>
```

i.e with close tag.. i wan to insert only  without  is that possible ????

Comment: Why don't you use append? I think, jquery is adding tags as a valid html.

Comment: Give me on logical reason wou want that happen. I am sure there must be a better way to achieve what you are trying overral

Comment: I may be wrong but rather than jQuery I think that's the browser that automatically closes tags that has not been properly closed, trying to fix incorrect html. You are probably trying to do something the wrong way. What's your end goal?

Comment: Why would you try to achieve this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you explain a bit better, maybe with an example, what you want to accomplish? From what I understood, you don't want a  close tag, is that it? The html output is a valid html, so I don't know the problem. If you just want the open tag, you can do:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("p").append('<span>');
  });
});
```

Comment: Well, @CaioFontes, your code will put the span withing the `p` element and close it like so: `<p>This is a paragraph.<span></span></p>`.

Comment: `append` inserts the `span` element as the last child to the `p` element. Regardless the `span` element will also have a closing tag.